# Plot not showing CDF

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot some cumulative distribution functions for different equations on the same plot, this is the code I have written:

```
library (triangle)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
n = 1000

W1 = rtriangle(n,3128,3250)
W2 = rtriangle(n,3065,3149)
SO = rtriangle(n,0.2,0.3)

MCtab <- data.frame(W1,W2,SO)

set.seed(1)
for (n in 1:n) {
NPV30 <- (1*W1 + 2*W2 + 3*SO )}

set.seed(1)
for (n in 1:n) {
NPV50 <- ecdf((4*W1 + 5*W2 + 6*SO ))}  
set.seed(1)
for (n in 1:n) {
NPV70 <- ecdf((7*W1 + 8*W2 + 9*SO))} 

MCtab2 <- data.frame(NPV30,NPV50,NPV70)



plot(NPV30, verticals=TRUE, main= 'Polymer NPV CDF', do.points=FALSE, col='red')
plot(NPV50, verticals=TRUE, do.points=FALSE, add=TRUE, col='brown')
plot(NPV70, verticals=TRUE, do.points=FALSE, add=TRUE, col='orange')
```

Only one plot is shown cant seem to figure out why, or if someone has a better approach would be great. Thanks

Comment: One possibility is that the later values are too large to be seen on the initial plot dimension. You might add a ylim argument that includes the minimum and maximum of all data points.

Comment: @lmo thanks that seems to be the most likely cause

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming there is an `ecdf` missing in front of your `NPV30` assignment in the sample code. I think the actual reason it is not displaying the values is that the `plot.ecdf` method simply does not support the `add` parameter. But you can roll your own pretty easily.

The values you chose for the functions give such different distributions that the cumulative distribution plot is pretty boring - just rectangles. So I adjusted the defining values for `NPV50` and `NPV70` to make the three distributions more similar.

So here is the code I used:

```
library (triangle)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
n = 50

W1 = rtriangle(n,3128,3250)
W2 = rtriangle(n,3065,3149)
SO = rtriangle(n,0.2,0.3)

MCtab <- data.frame(W1,W2,SO)

set.seed(1)
for (n in 1:n) {
  NPV30 <- ecdf((1*W1 + 2*W2 + 3*SO ))}

set.seed(1)
for (n in 1:n) {
  NPV50 <- ecdf((1*W1 + 2.2*W2 + 3.1*SO ))}  
set.seed(1)
for (n in 1:n) {
  NPV70 <- ecdf((1*W1 + 2.4*W2 + 3.2*SO))} 

MCtab2 <- data.frame(NPV30,NPV50,NPV70)

qNPV30 <- quantile(NPV30)
qNPV50 <- quantile(NPV50)
qNPV70 <- quantile(NPV70)
xmin <- min(c(qNPV30[1],qNPV50[1],qNPV70[1]))
xmax <- max(c(qNPV30[5],qNPV50[5],qNPV70[5]))
xdlt <- xmax-xmin

npts <- 200
x <- (1:npts)*xdlt/npts + xmin
y30 <- NPV30(x)
y50 <- NPV50(x)
y70 <- NPV70(x)

plot(x,y30,main= 'Polymer NPV CDF',xlim=c(xmin,xmax),type='l',col='red')
lines(x,y50,xlim=c(xmin,xmax),type='l',col='blue',add=T)
lines(x,y70,xlim=c(xmin,xmax),type='l',col='green',add=T)

#plot(NPV30, verticals=TRUE, main= 'Polymer NPV CDF', do.points=FALSE, col='red')
#plot(NPV50, verticals=TRUE, do.points=F, add=TRUE, col='blue')
#plot(NPV70, verticals=TRUE, do.points=F, add=TRUE, col='green')
```

and here is the resulting output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the clarification (apologies for the extremely  late reply)